# Load language files with Vite & i18next backend returns html file instead of json

Tags: vite, public, i18next

I want to load the translation.json files for the individual languages using i18next-http-backend, so I put them as static files in my public folder, eg: public/en/translation.json.

### The problem is, that the dev server returns a html file instead of the json file.

[image]

The backend plugin tries to fetch from http://localhost:5173/locales/en/translation.json which seems correct.

This is my code:

```
import i18n from 'i18next';
import { initReactI18next } from 'react-i18next';
import LanguageDetector from 'i18next-browser-languagedetector';
import Backend from 'i18next-http-backend';

i18n
  // load translation using http -> see /public/locales (i.e. https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next/tree/master/example/react/public/locales)
  // learn more: https://github.com/i18next/i18next-http-backend
  .use(Backend)
  // detect user language
  // learn more: https://github.com/i18next/i18next-browser-languageDetector
  .use(LanguageDetector)
  // pass the i18n instance to react-i18next.
  .use(initReactI18next)
  // init i18next
  // for all options read: https://www.i18next.com/overview/configuration-options
  .init({
    fallbackLng: 'en',
    debug: true,
    load: 'languageOnly',

    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false // not needed for react as it escapes by default
    },

    backend: {
      overrideMimeType: 'application/json', // tried with this and without
      loadPath: '/locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json'
    }
  });


export default i18n;
```

the favicon.png, which is also located inside the public folder, is loaded fine, so I dont know whats the problem with the json files is.

Comment: Solution: I had the files named as translations.json (with an 's' at the end) but the backend tries to load 'translation.json', so this was not found and vite returns for whatever reason a html file instead of throwing an error.

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar problem after migration from CRA to Vite.
In my case, I get the translation file from a different backend server. And the problem was in getting json file instead html.

So I tried to use the proxy and it helped! Try:

```
export default defineConfig({
  server: {
    proxy: {
      '/api': {
        target: SOME_URL,
        changeOrigin: true,
      },
    },
  },
})
```

docs: https://vitejs.dev/config/server-options.html#server-proxy